# jest test call of method that is not mocked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, ts-jest

I have a React Component `MyComponent` where I want to test behavior that should be triggered when a user rotates their phone.

Inside the Component:

```js
export class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent<props> {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('orientationchange', this.onRotation)
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('orientationchange', this.onRotation)
  }

  onRotation = () => {
    // do things
  }

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I found an article on medium that describes how to write tests for this [here](https://medium.com/@DavideRama/testing-global-event-listener-within-a-react-component-b9d661e59953). However, that doesn't work for me.

```js
describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
  it('does things on rotation', () => {
    const map : any = {}
    window.addEventListener = jest.fn((event, cb) => {
      map[event] = cb;
    })

    const wrapper : any = mount(<MyComponent />)
    map.orientationchange()

    expect(wrapper.onRotation).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

In the article this works, however I get an error:

```
"Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function
Received has value: undefined"
```

Using a spy also doesn't work:

```js
it('does things on rotation', () => {
    const map : any = {}
    window.addEventListener = jest.fn((event, cb) => {
      map[event] = cb;
    })

    const wrapper : any = mount(<MyComponent />)
    const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'onRotation')

    map.orientationchange()
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

It says:

```
"Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called."
```

Comment: i think you should test code within onRotation instead of checking if your onRotation is called or not.

Comment: yes, you're right, I'll do that instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spy on function inside onRotation.

```
import React from 'react';

class OrientationChange extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      window.addEventListener('orientationchange', this.onRotation)
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
      window.removeEventListener('orientationchange', this.onRotation)
    }
    handleRotation = () => {
      console.log('inside handle rotation');
    }

    onRotation = (event) => {
      this.handleRotation()
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>Testing</div>
        )
    }
}

export default OrientationChange;

describe('<OrientationChange /> orientation change test', () => {
  it('does things on rotation', () => {
    const map = {}
    window.addEventListener = jest.fn((event, cb) => {
      map[event] = cb;
    })

    const wrapper = mount(<OrientationChange />)

    const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'handleRotation')
    map.orientationchange();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```